# Performing modular arithmetic in Java to implement Diffie-Hellman

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman, modular-arithmetic

I have a question, I am trying to implement the encryption protocol between server and client based on Diffie-Hellman problem.

The problem is when I tried to `((t^RsRc) mod p)^(1/Rc mod q)`  it is not giving me `(t^Rs) mod p`.

I have checked even if I am  doing 
`((t^Rc) mod p)^(1/Rc mod q)
t.modPow(Rc, p)).modPow(Rc.modInverse(q), p)` it is not giving me `t`.

Comment: What does your code look like? In particular, what data types are you using for your calculations?

Comment: You've got your mod p's and mod q's mixed up.